# Varnish 4 Cache does not cache dynamic page

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

It is possible cache of dynamic pages, especially the home page?

For plan to reduce access to the database .

I can do static file cache. perfect.

**Response headers**

> Accept-Ranges:bytes
>
> Age:0
>
> Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
>
> Connection:keep-alive
>
> Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
>
> Date:Tue, 09 Dec 2014 17:07:13 GMT
>
> Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
>
> Pragma:no-cache
>
> Transfer-Encoding:chunked
>
> Via:1.1 varnish-v4
>
> x-Cache:uncached
>
> X-Varnish:295421

File default vcl: http://notepad.cc/vaokodde9

Comment: Maybe show the headers returned by the webserver that you have put Varnish in front of?

Comment: would it? http://notepad.cc/qietheemme20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your backend is screamming it doesn't want anyone to cache the page:

```
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
```

It's setting all the Cache-Control headers to disallow cache, it's setting an Expires header in the past (way back), and a Pragma: no-cache. You either have to fix the backend to send headers that allow caching, or if you are sure that you won't break anything start to workaround this headers in vcl.

I would choose the first option, and work the Cookies issue later.

Answer (score 0):

I think Varnish by default does not cache pages with Cookies. Maybe that is your problem (it looks like you have a PHPSESSID and some other stuff)?

See the Varnish documentation: https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExampleCacheCookies

Try configuring your webserver to not set any cookies, or configure Varnish to ignore them (note that that may not make sense, and break your website!)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all . I managed to solve the problem by studying a little about the functioning of the cookie in the varnish .